# How to sort multi-dimensional array in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I'm having a two dimensional array as follows

```
NSArray *cities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"New Delhi",@"Karachi",@"Dhaka",@"Columbu", nil];
NSArray *distance = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"500",@"1400",@"1200",@"2800", nil];
NSMutableArray *details= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:cities.count];
[details addObject:cities];
[details addObject:distance];
```

Now, the `details` array looks like

```
(
    (
    "New Delhi",
    Karachi,
    Dhaka,
    Columbu
 ),
    (
    500,
    1400,
    1200,
    2800
 )
)
```

I need to sort the array with ascending order w.r.t `distance` array
ie,

```
(
    (
    "New Delhi",
    Dhaka,
    Karachi,
    Columbu
 ),
    (
    500,
    1200,
    1400,
    2800
 )
)
```

how to do this?

I also need to sort the whole array by alphabetical order w.r.t `cities` array.

I tried using `sortUsingComparator` but, can't get the solution completely.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980513/objective-c-sort-two-dimensional-array

Comment: I have given an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16710509/767730) to a similar question, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.arrayForRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrayForCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Mumbai",@"Vizag",@"Hyderabad",@"Ahemdabad",@"Secunderabad", nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrayForDistance = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"200",@"320",@"32",@"450",@"14", nil];

    for (int i=0; i<arrayForCities.count; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *tempDicts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [tempDicts setObject:[arrayForCities objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"names"];
        [tempDicts setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[arrayForDistance objectAtIndex:i] intValue]] forKey:@"distance"];
        [self.arrayForRows addObject:tempDicts];
    }

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
    [self.arrayForRows sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: It's a coincidence that both of our [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16710509/767730) are very same.

Comment: I changed the sortdescriptor initwithkey to names object, it sorts the array with alphabatical order too. much needed help, thx again

Answer (score 1):

Structure is complicated. Make a class `city` containing `name` and `distance`. Then add objects of this class. Then you can sort using `city.distance`.