# Sort complete matrix (2d array) by column

Tags: objective-c, sorting

Lets say I have a 2D array of n-by-m and I wand to sort it by a certain column, and have the rest of the columns "move" in the same order, as they have a "meaning" per row.

example:

```
 name   number  somethingrepeatable
john    543       2
peter   4312      4
jane    234       2
```

Right now, the code that I have will sort the last column correctly, but will not distinguish between the john and jane row as the column the sort is applied on contains 2, giving me this as a result:

```
name    number  somethingrepeatable
john    543        2
jane    234        2
peter   4312       4
```

More than asking for the code itself, I'm asking for an idea on how I could resolve this problem.

This is my code so far:

```
- (Matrix*) sortByColumn: (NSUInteger) columnNumber{

NSMutableArray * column_in_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int k=0;k<[self numberOfRows];k++) @autoreleasepool{
    [column_in_array addObject: [self objectInRow:k column:columnNumber]];
}



NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil
                                              ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];




NSMutableArray *origPositions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[orderedColumn count]];
int pos;
NSNumber *posNSI = [[NSNumber alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<[orderedColumn count];i++){
    pos = (int)[column_in_array  indexOfObject:[orderedColumn objectAtIndex:i]];
    posNSI = [NSNumber numberWithInt:pos];
    [origPositions insertObject:posNSI atIndex:i];
}




Matrix * myReturnMatrix = [[Matrix alloc] initWithRows:[self numberOfRows]
                                      columns:[self numberOfColumns]];
NSUInteger index;
for(int i=0;i<[self numberOfRows];i++){
    for(int j=0;j<[self numberOfColumns];j++){
        index = [[origPositions objectAtIndex: i] integerValue];
        [myReturnArray setObject:[self objectInRow:index column:j] inRow:i column:j];
    }


}

return myReturnMatrix;
```

}

A quick "explanation" would be: 
I store the column I want to sort in an array, sort it using sortDescriptor, obtain the positions of the original column and sort the remaining columns using those original positions.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13980625/35499) may be helpful. It uses the sortedArrayUsingComparator: method of NSArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I came up with in the end to keep all columns "synced" with the one sorted, I had to make a new class so that I could store both "original position" and whatever data the column had:

```
 NSMutableArray * arrayForOrigPos_unsorted = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int k=0;k<[self numberOfRows];k++){
    origPosition *oP = [[origPosition alloc]init];
    [oP setMyOrigPos:k];
    [oP setMyObj:[self objectInRow:k column:columnNumber]];
    [arrayForOrigPos_unsorted addObject: oP];
}
NSArray *arrayForOrigPos_sorted = nil;


if(!allNumbers){
    arrayForOrigPos_sorted = [arrayForOrigPos_unsorted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(origPosition *a, origPosition *b) {
        return [a.myObj localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:b.myObj];
    }];
}else{
    arrayForOrigPos_sorted = [arrayForOrigPos_unsorted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(origPosition *a, origPosition *b) {
        return [a.myObj compare:b.myObj options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];
}


Matrix * nuevo = [[Matrix alloc] initWithRows:[self numberOfRows]
                                      columns:[self numberOfColumns]];
NSUInteger indice;
for(int i=0;i<[self numberOfRows];i++){
    for(int j=0;j<[self numberOfColumns];j++){
        if([[arrayForOrigPos_sorted objectAtIndex: i] respondsToSelector:@selector(myOrigPos)]){
            indice = [[arrayForOrigPos_sorted objectAtIndex: i] myOrigPos];
            [nuevo setObject:[self objectInRow:indice column:j] inRow:i column:j];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to do a multi-key sort: your primary key is the last column and your secondary key is the first column (and maybe your tertiary key is the middle column).

You can achieve this by taking the approach of your algorithm one step further:

1. Create an `NSMutableArray` containing the values `0` through `numberOfRows-1`, i.e. the row indicies rather than values from your matrix.
2. Sort this array using `sortUsingComparator:` (or `sortWithOptions:usingComparator:` if you need, say, a stable sort). This method will be given two indicies and should compare the corresponding rows in matrix.
3. Produce your result matrix by permuting the rows in the order now given in the sorted array.

In brief outline pseudo-code this is:

```
NSMutableArray *arrangement = [NSMutableArray new];
// fill arrangement with @0 through @(numberOfRows-1), i.e. NSNumber objects

[arrangement sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
 {
    NSUInteger firstIndex = [obj1 unsignedIntegerValue];
    NSUInteger secondIndex = [obj2 unsignedIntegerValue];
    // compare matrix rows firstIndex & secondIndex
    // first compare values in last column,
    // if last column values are equal compare values in first column
    // ditto for middle column if required
 }];

 // arrangement now contains the sorted order of the rows - construct result matrix
```

HTH

Comment: Indeed, as I am trying to do a multi-key sort, being the primary key passed as an argument to my method, I am going to try to pass your reply to working code, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a custom NSSortDescriptor

It might also be easier if your model was one array of NSDictionary objects.